# Hyperledger Fabric Errror : Query - Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Failed to get block number 1, error Entry not found in index

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to execute balance-transfer application that ship in fabric-samples of hyperledger. Source code path git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git

All steps executed as below 
Channel created 
Joined channel on Org1
Joined channel on Org2
Successfully Installed chaincode on organization org1
Successfully Installed chaincode on organization org2

but instantiate of chaincode operation is failing on peers. 
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. I am struggling from last one week. I am using docker container on ubuntu v16.

Error Log:

```
[2017-10-02 05:11:11.374] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {<br/>
  r: <BN: 4824699f0a1d1a0fc696df545fb3379dffc6b46124619f53672359a6755bc7ff>,<br/>
  s: <BN: 49fc91b2a7800eff5396053d4d8ff2683167a9e3f52ccc43228143f9b5741168>,<br/>
  recoveryParam: 0 }
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Failed to get block number 1, error Entry not found in index)<br/>
    at /home/02102017/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15<br/>
error: [Channel.js]: Failed Query block. Error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Failed to get block number 1, error Entry not found in index)<br/>
    at /home/02102017/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15<br/>
[2017-10-02 05:11:11.472] [ERROR] Query - Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Failed to get block number 1, error Entry not found in index)<br/>
    at /home/02102017/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15<br/>
```

**Isssue resolve after increasing request-timeout in file 
 fabric-samples-master/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/config/default.json**

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to overwrite **fabric-samples-master/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/config/default.json**. There is a open issue on  JIRA https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-884 regarding request timeout. 
and For now as a workaround you could set it globally before making the call.

```
const temp = client.getConfigSetting('request-timeout');
client.setConfigSetting('request-timeout', 60000);
... make your call ...
client.setConfigSetting('request-timeout', temp);
```

Hope it will work for you.